# Error with my .htaccess file :/

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a small website and i want to use a .htaccess file to make my URIs more search engine friendly. My problem is, that my CSS files can't be find. I use the following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Maybe many of you know this code. My website stucture is the following:

```
/
-css
 -layout.css
-images
 -image.jpg
-js
 -jquery.js
-includes
 -controller
 -model
 -view
-.htaccess
-index.php
```

When I load my website, the css parts are not loading. My template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $this->title ? $this->title : 'MVC Beispiel'; ?></title>
        <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    $content
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried different ways. Shouldn't the following code stop the module to rewrite the request for css files:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (\.css)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

It would be really glad, if you could help me, to find a solution. :/ Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: Most errors concerning files not being found can be solved by using absolute paths (`/css/layout.css`) instead of relative ones. Since a user request will look like `/view/pages/pageID`, a relative path will mess things up (user requests `/view/css/layout.css`). Have you tried absolute paths yet?

Comment: Did you check file permissions? Can you access the `.css` files when you clear / disable `.htaccess`? If you can access e.g. your `.js` files and not `.css` files (their siblings), probably not related to `.htaccess`.

Comment: Hey, I tried to use absolute paths and now it works. :D Thank you. :D